# How to write the resultant of NMinimaize as a vector?

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, vector

I used NMinimize, and I get a result which after some modification is like:

```
   avec = {x$1 -> 0.50978, x$3 -> 0.508274, x$4 -> 0.431230, 
   x$5 -> 0.46221, x$6 -> 0.554047}
```

Do you know any way to change this to a list of numbers? In other words I want to get rid of the x$ symbols and arrows and just have the numbers as a list:

```
   { 0.50978, 0.508274,  0.431230, 
    0.46221,  0.554047}
```

Thank you

Comment: `avec // Values`

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Or `Last /@ avec`